# Random restarts - software or hardware related?

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, reboot

I experience random restarts. Hardware is new and worked good for approx. 2 months. How to explore and locate the possible reasons e.g. by using the logs or checking the hardware?

Processor: 11th Gen Intel© Core™ i5-11400 @ 2.60GHz × 6 (with Intel Corporation RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730])

OS: Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon v. 5.8.4 - Linux Kernel: 5.15.0-87-generic

M.2 SSD: Patriot model: Viper VP4300L 2TB size: 1.82 TiB

Comment: Always the best thing to do here is to get the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and test all the hardware.